# Secure WCF service on Azure

Tags: wcf-security

We have a WCF service running in Azure and have client application (WPF) consuming the servcie. Can anybody point me  in the right direction on how I can secure the WCF service so that only my client application can access the public methods or applications allowed can access the public methods

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of possibilities depending on binding you are using, an approach could be to use Message Security with X509 certification in WSHtttpBinding
[you can read about it's example here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/09/24/931.aspx)

- Disable Mex (Api information)
- Use HTTPS to prevent man in middle attacks

these are general ideas based on your environment and constraints it can be different.