# Hosting wcf services in Windows Azure Platform

Tags: wcf, azure

I am working on a .Net application that uses the WCF to communicate with the business layer. The WCF services are hosted in a windows service.

Now I am transferring the application to a cloud application using the windows azure platform, so I hosted my WCF service in a worker role and they are working normally.

I want to know if this is the correct decision to host the WCF services in a worker role or is there any another better solution to do so.

Comment: Can you share some details around the decision to host the service in a windows service vs. in IIS? broadly speaking the same consideratoins will apply in Azure when choosing between a web role and a worker role....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have (2) options - [Web or Worker Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179367.aspx) (*or VM - but that isn't useful here*). Worker Roles will never *restart* to release memory, while Web Roles will recycle (*unless using [IIS autostart/AlwaysRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285.aspx)*). Essentially - they are doing the same thing (*they even [use the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816250/175679)*). The only issue I could see is how IIS manages process lifetime versus a standard windows always-running process. The other consideration is that IIS (web role) probably has more security checks and permissions than the standard windows process (worker role). I would certainly take a look at [improving the default security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423447/175679) of your WCF host.